# Json does not go to next or previous text when clicking on button with using Linq in C#

Tags: c#, json, linq

In the steps from my json file, I want to construct a linq that moves to the next or previous text depending on whether you hit the back button (previous id) or the next button (next contentid). If this occurs, the label's text must be modified. I'm not sure how to accomplish that in Linq.

**The problem** now is when I click the button the first time the text is empty. And then he shows the same text! What am I doing wrong?

#### Buttons' Click handlers

```
private Content content;
public void BtnNext_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var index = content == null ? 0 : _step.Contents.IndexOf(content) + 1;
    content = _step.Contents.ElementAtOrDefault(index);
    lblText.Text = content?.Text;
}

public void BtnBack_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var index = content == null ? _step.Contents.Count - 1 : _step.Contents.IndexOf(content) - 1;
    content = _step.Contents.ElementAtOrDefault(index);
    lblText.Text = content?.Text;
}
```

#### Domain classes

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("protocols")]
    public List<Protocol> Protocols { get; set; }
}

public class Protocol
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("steps")]
    public List<Step> Steps { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("versie")]
    public string Versie { get; set; }
}

public class Step
{
    [JsonProperty("chapterTitle")]
    public string ChapterTitle { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("contents")]
    public List<Content> Contents { get; set; }
}

public class Content
{
    [JsonProperty("contentid")]
    public int Contentid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

#### The json file

```json
{
  "protocols": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Pols meten",
      "steps": [
        {
          "chapterTitle": "Voorzorg",
          "contents": [
            {
              "contentid": "1",
              "text": "voor blabla"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "contents": [
            {
              "contentid": "2",
              "text": "voor blabla2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "chapterTitle": "Handeling",
          "contents": [
            {
              "contentid": "3",
              "text": "handeling blabla"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "contens": [
            {
              "contentid": "4",
              "text": "handeling blabla2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "chapterTitle": "Nazorg",
          "contents": [
            {
              "contentid": "5",
              "text": "nazorg blabla"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "contents": [
            {
              "contentid": "6",
              "text": "nazorg blabla2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "versie": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

What i want is show the text from the next or previous content id based where you clicked on.

Comment: What if you store the currently displayed content index (`currentId`) in a class level field? Then the prev button code would be: `var index = --currentId > 0 ? currentId : 0; lblText.Text = _step.Contents[index]?.Text;`. The next button code: `var index = ++currentId < _step.Contents.Count ? currentId : _step.Contents.Count - 1; lblText.Text = _step.Contents[index]?.Text;`

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each step has ONE content :

```json
...
"steps": [
  {
    "chapterTitle": "Voorzorg",
    "contents": [
      {
        "contentid": "1",
        "text": "voor blabla"
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
```

First click on the next button that display nothing :

```cs
// Initialized on the first step's content (I think)
private Content content;
public void BtnNext_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index;
    if(content == null)
    {
        index = 0;
    }
    else // Go here, because content is the first step's content (that is not null)
    {
        index = _step.Contents.IndexOf(content)
        // index <= 0
        index = index + 1;
        // index <= 1
    }
    content = _step.Contents.ElementAtOrDefault(index);
    // content <= _step.Contents.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
    // content <= the second step's content
    // But the step has ONE content, then ElementAtOrDefault return null
    // content <= null
    lblText.Text = content?.Text;
    // Display nothing
}
```

Second click on the next button :

```cs
// After the first click, content is null
private Content content;
public void BtnNext_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index;
    if(content == null) // Go here, because content is null
    {
        index = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        index = _step.Contents.IndexOf(content) + 1;
    }
    content = _step.Contents.ElementAtOrDefault(index);
    // content <= _step.Contents.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
    // content <= the first step's content
    lblText.Text = content?.Text;
    // Redisplay the first step's content
}
```

You can keep the index (rather than the content) and check that it is in the range (rather than the content is not null) :

```cs
private int index;
public void BtnNext_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    index++;
    // If the index go after the last element
    if(index >= _step.Contents.Count)
        // Then reset
        index = 0;
    var content = _step.Contents.ElementAtOrDefault(index);
    lblText.Text = content?.Text;
}



public void BtnBack_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    index--;
    // If the index go before the first element
    if(index < 0)
        // Then go to the last
        index = _step.Contents.Count - 1;
    var content = _step.Contents.ElementAtOrDefault(index);
    lblText.Text = content?.Text;
}
```

And add more content in the steps (else this loop on the unique step's content) :

```json
"steps": [
  {
    "chapterTitle": "Voorzorg",
    "contents": [
      {
        "contentid": "1",
        "text": "voor blabla"
      },
      {
        "contentid": "2",
        "text": "vuur blabla"
      },
      {
        "contentid": "3",
        "text": "soor blybli"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: When a chapter's last content is displayed, maybe the next button need to display the next chapter's first content (rather than loop on the current chapter).

Comment: In the next code (that works) : `lblText.Text = content?.Text;`.
In the prec code (that break) : `lblText.Text = content.Text;`.
Do you see the diff?

Comment: In my precedent comment, the diff was '?'. The [Null-conditional operators(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) avoid to call on a null reference.

Comment: In the question's code, BtnNext_Clicked manage the current element in the field `index` and BtnBack_Clicked manage the current element in the field `content`. You need to rewrite the method BtnBack_Clicked to that use the field `index`.

Comment: You are approaching the solution. Try to image that do BtnBack_Clicked when the field `index` has the value 0. After `index--`, the field index has the value -1. Now look at what the if checks. It checks if `index` is upper the interval, but in this case `index` is lower the interval. Inconsistent?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the method BtnBack_Clicked`.

Comment: How to go to next chapter... Can you show all fields in the class?

Comment: The json is good, else the code will well before.